# GCM: how to send paylaod?

Tags: android

I used the demo GCM example provided by Google, it works fine, except it sends by default message "GCM: you received message!", I would like to alert to send instead a string, but dont know how?

Server code:

```
 Message message =new Message.Builder().addData("data", "hello client").build();

     Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId, 5);
```

Client Code:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


            String details = intent.getStringExtra("data");
            System.out.println("Message="+details);

        }
```

does any body have an example of GCM example with payload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

man, i found the show notification message is local ,not from the server.....

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}
```

you will find the program set message to R.string.gcm_message.....